# Upload a file from Play webapp to another website using java.io.FileInputStream with Scala

Tags: java, scala, file-upload, playframework

In my controller I defined a method upload that is supposed to stream a file that is uploaded from a user to a third party website (like Dropbox or Box.com) via my website. I am limit by the JavaApi (for which I wrote a wrapper). I have to give it a java.io.FileInputStream but I don't know how.

This is the method:

```
def upload(parentId: String) = Action.async { implicit request =>
    authorized(request, { user =>
      val body = request.body.asMultipartFormData

      // somehow i have to transform the body from request to a FileInputStream

      val stream: FileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file)

      ApiJava.pseudoUpload(user.token, parentId, stream);
      Redirect(routes.Application.showFolder(parentId))
    })
  }
```

The request is send with the standard

```
@helper.form(action = routes.File.pseudoUpload(currentId), 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data") {
                <input type="file" name="upoadThis">
                <input type="submit">
                }
```

Your help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
def upload(parentId: String) = Action.async(parse.multipartFormData) { implicit request =>
    authorized(request, { user =>
      request.body.file("upoadThis").map { uploadThis =>
        new FileInputStream(receivedFile.ref.file)
        ...
```

That stores file temporarily to disk, before streaming it out to Dropbox or whoever.

See [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaFileUpload) for more on this.

Comment: It compiles and runs which is quite helpful already. Thanks! Unfortunately nothing happens and I'm not sure why.

Comment: I'd put in `receivedFile.ref.moveTo(File("/tmp/upload", replace = true)` as the first thing to do in the `.map` block. You can then check in `/tmp` whether the `upload` file is there and its content.

Comment: Okay! I got it. I had a typo as visible in the code above. In the form header I named the file "upoadThis" and requested "uploadThis" in the controller! Classic! So your code works and makes me feel ashamed because it's so short and simple. Thanks a lot! Made my day!

Comment: Your last two sentences make my day too! :)